# PHP MYSQLI Query is failing

Tags: php, mysqli

When trying to run a MYSQLI command in PHP, Its coming back failing.

```
function DB_query($query, $params = []) {
    $conn = DB_connect();
    if ($params)
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $types = str_repeat('s', count($params));
        $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
    } else {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }
    if ($result)
    {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
        return $result;
    } else {
        return mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
    }
}
```

Here is my query:

```
DB_query("SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1",[$email])
```

It runs on:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
```

The results from $result: array(1)([0]=>array(1)([0]=>(int)1))

Here is my query:

```
DB_query("SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1",[$email]);
```

It runs on:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
```

The results from $result: > array(0)

---

I have tried changing out the "mysqli_fetch_all" to fetch_all, but I cant figure it out. I need both query to run through the same function.
I cant figure out why the last query is returning nothing in the array.

Comment: `Its coming back failing.`  What does this mean, an empty result is not it failing it's just an empty result.  Maybe your email is wrong.  I won't mention how the logic is flawed, a query should return a consistent type of value, `if (!$result) mysqli_affected_rows($conn)` why would you return the number of affected rows when you don't get a result...  I would think returning Boolean `false` or an array of results would be better... just saying.

Comment: As @ArtisticPhoenix mentioned, please check your database and your test email. There is no problem with your `DB_query` function. I tried it in my local environment and it works.

Comment: One more note: your two queries didn't prove anything. In the first query, you used count (*), so there must be one row returned (containing 0) even there is no matched record in database.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to your database successfully? Try limiting your scope when fail tracking. Here, database connection comes first in that line.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '".$email."'";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
     echo $row[0];
     echo $row[1];
     echo $row[2];
   }
?>
```

Alternatively, you can use [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) and use `$row['fieldname']` inside the loop.